# oracle service name registration

Tags: oracle

```
PDBAAIT =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1523))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1524))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1525))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PDBAAIT)
    )
  )
```

I copied it from tnsnames.ora. I want to know what all this things are? What does this snippet does in oracle? Does this snippet have a relationship with listener?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tns-ora-file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do you understand what purpose is served by the tnsnames.ora file in the first place?

The first line shown (PDBAAIT =) is known as the "net service name". It serves as an alias for all that follows.  A client specifies this value to indicate what database it wants to connect to:

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@PDBAAIT
```

When the client passes its connection request to the oracle networking layer (tns), the next step is that tns looks up this entry, and uses the information there to build the request that is passed on to the OS network stack and on to the listener.

The ADDRESS= lines specify what network protocol is to be used, the name of the server to which this request is to be routed, and the port on that server that the listener is using.  BTW, there is no valid reason to be specifying a list of ports like that.  The default port for the listener is 1521, and there is very rarely any reason to use any other port, or to list multiple ports. Burn this into your brain: "one single listenr, with the default name of LISTENER, using the single default port of 1521, IS quite capable of -- indeed, ***was designed to*** -- service multiple databases of mulitple versions running from multiple ORACLE_HOME locations."

Also note that in this case it is specifying HOST=localhost.  'localhost' is the alias for ip address 127.0.0.1, which is the loopback address.  Requests for this destination never leave the requesting machine.  So this host specification will only work if the client and database are on the same machine.

Under CONNECT_DATA, the SERVER=DEDICATED tells the listener to spawn a dedicated server process for this client request.  As opposed to handing it off to a shared dispatcher process.

Finally, the SERVICE_NAME=PDBAAIT tells the listener that you want to connect to the database that is using the service name PDBAAIT.